# Mouse flickering

Tags: mouse, cursor

I've just done a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10 on my Asus K53SV but I noticed that the cursor is flickering a lot and some times disappear. I never had this issue before with other Ubuntu release. What can I do?

Answer (score 10):

System Settings > Screen Display. There is an unknown monitor. Disable it, it should be good

Comment: Whats with this unknown display anyway? What is it? Where did it come from?

Answer (score 1):

You could try disabling the gnome-settings-daemon `cursor` plugin, then doing a restart or log out/in

To do so run this in a terminal

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```

If desiring to reactivate then just rerun the command but use `true` instead of `false`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Asus K53SM.I tried to disable unknown display(if it exists), which is  located in `System Settings > Hardware > Displays`.