# Mouse pointer blinking

Tags: mouse, 13.10

After installing Ubuntu 13.10 mouse is blinking and sometimes it blinks so fast that I can't see where it is, especially on web pages. It also happens even if I don't work anything on computer.

During setup of installation I pointed /home to previous 13.04 Ubuntu, maybe some settings are obsolete. What could be problem here?
I have NVidia 525M graphic card.

Comment: you can try what I posted here, may help, may not. If it does help would be good to know so I can update a current bug I have on the cursor plugin http://askubuntu.com/questions/360455/mouse-flickering

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This worked for me. System Settings > Screen Display. There is an unknown monitor. Disable it, it should be good. This is not my solution, i got it from here.
https://askubuntu.com/a/360473

Comment: Worked perfectly. Any idea why that second display is there?

Comment: Truthfully, no idea.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but I have no unknown monitors.

Comment: works with 14.04LTS

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to System Settings > Displays.

   [image: a screenshot of Displays, in System Settings, showing Built-in Display and Unknown Display]
2. Turn-off / disable *Unknown Display*.